# How to Find All Possible Partitions of A Number

Tags: perl

```
sub partition {
    print "@_\n";
    my ( $largest, @rest ) = @_;
    my $min = $rest[0] || 1;
    my $max = int( $largest / 2 );
    for my $n ( $min .. $max ) {
        partition( $largest - $n, $n, @rest );
    }
}
```

I found this code on internet that prints all possible partitions if used as
`&partition(number)` but i want it to assign all possible partitions to a 
variable called `$numbers`. Can any one modify this to make it like this:

```
&partition(3);
#and assigns them to $numbers like this
$numbers = "1+1+1:1+2:2+1";
```

The code above prints every possible partition but it doesn't find
every possible combination.

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to expand a bit to explain what algorithm you'd be using. Given a selection of inputs, what's the desired outputs?

Comment: I want this assignment to be made : $numbers = "1+1+1:1+2:2+1"     when i use this subroutine &partition(3).

Comment: And what is the problem you are having with making this modification?

Comment: Also - can you expand on what you mean by 'doesn't find every possible combination'? What would you be seeking there?

Comment: By doesnt find every possible combination i mean it finds 2+1+1 but it doesnt find 1+2+1 or 1+1+2.

Comment: So for each 'returned value' you want to permute them?

Comment: Exactly, i am new at Perl sorry i bothered you a lot but how do i do that?

Comment: Fortunately, this is a [frequently asked question](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-permute-N-elements-of-a-list)

Comment: Thanks for all your help have a good day sir

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
sub partition {
    my @partitions = join("+", @_);

    my ( $largest, @rest ) = @_;
    my $min = $rest[0] || 1;
    my $max = int( $largest / 2 );
    for my $n ( $min .. $max ) {
        push @partitions, partition( $largest - $n, $n, @rest );
    }

    return join(':', @partitions);
}
```

Method 2: (Uses less memory)

```
sub partition {
    my @partitions;

    local *_partition = sub {
        push @partitions, join("+", @_);

        my ( $largest, @rest ) = @_;
        my $min = $rest[0] || 1;
        my $max = int( $largest / 2 );
        for my $n ( $min .. $max ) {
            _partition( $largest - $n, $n, @rest );
        }
    };

    _partition(@_);
    return join(':', @partitions);
}
```